# javascript- "You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression"; CategoryInfo: InvalidOperation: (:) [],

Tags: javascript, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

Not sure this question was already posted in Stack overflow.
I have created a jenkins job to deploy the application and at the end to update a file called "schemes.xml" with the version details.
The interesting thing is jenkins build shows "success" and the files are deployed properly, but it doesn't updating the version details into the "schemes.xml" file.

Would be great if anyone can fix this please. 
**Code:**

```
            <![CDATA[
                var myproperty= project.getProperty("FolderStructure");
                if (myproperty!= null) {
                    project.setProperty("DestinationFolderStructure", myproperty.trim())
                }
            ]]>
        </script>
```

**ERROR**

```
[exec] You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
     [exec]     + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeExceptionDeploying to D:\apps\dotNet\PolarisDictionaries\Polaris\IrishMotor\Schemes.xml
```

Comment: Your question is tagged [tag:powershell], but the code you've posted looks like javascript

Comment: looks like project is null

Comment: Thanks all for your reply. 
Actually its my typo that i missed last date in the schemes.xml file. all good now.